# UIBarButtonItems appear in the wrong order

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have a test application in **monotouch** with a single UIViewController. I want to add 3 UIBarButtonItems

```
    UIBarButtonItem b1 = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action);
    UIBarButtonItem b2 = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add);
    UIBarButtonItem b3 = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Bookmarks);

    this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(new [] {b1,b2,b3}, true);
```

Unfortunately they appear in the wrong order. First i see b3 then b2 and lastly b1.
What i am trying to achieve is for the UIBarButtonItems to appear in the following order b1,b2,b3.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that's just because right bar buttons are added from right to left, so just change your array order to {b3,b2,b1}.

Comment: It is clearly stated in the Documentation, however the right to left logic seems confusing to mee

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setLeftBarButtonItems:animated: ?

Here's a link to the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationItem/setLeftBarButtonItems:animated